# .NET 6 Google Authentication - Allow user to set password before signing In

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, google-authentication

I have added `Google` authentication in a .NET 6 application. Everything is working fine. The user is redirected to Google for authentication and after successful authentication redirected back to my application callback URL.
So after successful authentication, the authentication middleware `Sign's In` the user and creates a `cookie`.

What I want is that before the user is signed In and the cookie is created, I want the user to enter a `password` like redirecting the user to a set password page but by the time the callback method is called after authentication, the user is already signed in and the cookie has been created. I want to create a cookie and log a user in only after the user enters the password.

It's like the user has authenticated through Google but I want them to set the password as well so I can save it in the database.

**Program.cs**

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/Forbidden/";
            options.LoginPath = "/account/register/";
        })
        .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
        {
            googleOptions.ClientId = "*******";
            googleOptions.ClientSecret = "********";
            googleOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            
        });
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
public async Task GoogleAuth()
{
    await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = Url.Action("AuthCallback", "Account")
    });
}    

public async Task<IActionResult> AuthCallback()
    {
        //This method is called when a user successfully authenticates with Google.    
        //At this point, the user is signed in and a cookie has been created.    
        //I want the user to enter their password before they are signed in.
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a temp cookie authentication scheme and set that for Google `SignInScheme`.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/Forbidden/";
    options.LoginPath = "/account/register/";
})
.AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = "*******";
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = "********";
    googleOptions.SignInScheme = "temp-cookie"; // change here
})
.AddCookie("temp-cookie", options => // add temp-cookie scheme
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/Forbidden/";
    options.LoginPath = "/account/register/";
});
```

Check for temp-cookie scheme in the callback and set the default scheme after user set the password.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AuthCallback()
{
    // check for temp-cookie authentication
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("temp-cookie");

    return View("SetPassword");
}

public async Task<IActionResult> SetPassword()
{
    ...
    // after setting the password

    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("temp-cookie");

    // sign in the user with default cookie scheme
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(result.Principal);

    // delete temporary cookie 
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("temp-cookie");
}
```

Comment: Hi, so in the controller if i use [Authorize] attribute I will need to specify the default authentication scheme that is Cookie. Something like  
[ Authorize ( AuthenticationSchemes = "Cookie" ) ] so it only considers Cookie as valid authentication scheme and not temp-cookie?

Comment: You are right, but you probably don't need to do that, because nowhere in the pipeline you are validating the temp-cookie scheme. The authentication middleware would only authenticate using the default scheme which is Cookie in your case.